# Большой размер при компиляции apk в Unity

Tags: android, unity3d

Большой размер при компиляции apk в Unity

```
Textures      0.0 kb     0.0% 
Meshes        0.0 kb     0.0% 
Animations    0.0 kb     0.0% 
Sounds        0.0 kb     0.0% 
Shaders       0.0 kb     0.0% 
Other Assets  0.1 kb     0.0% 
Levels        16.0 kb    0.3% 
Scripts       723.7 kb   15.1% 
Included DLLs 3.9 mb     84.3% 
File headers  8.4 kb     0.2% 
Complete size 4.7 mb     100.0%
```

Файл на диске D весит 18 мегабайт.

Как так я не понимаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что библиотеки столько весят. У меня знакомы как-то сделать наипростейшую игру и она весила 250 метров, хотя там делов на метра 1-2

Comment: Это понятно, но а что разве вы не пробовали искать способы, ведь они есть.

Но смое странное то что на сайте Unity есть скриншот где рассказывает о том как уменшить размер APK. И там Complete size 14 метров. и файл apk 14. А у меня Complet 4.7 а файл apk 18.

Comment: Честно сказать я сам никогда не работал с Unity, скорее в ознакомительных целях поставил и поковырялся, но у меня знакомый работал с ней и сказал, что был таков результат из-за большого веса библиотеки, в любом случае Игры на Unity будут весить гораздо больше, чем если бы вы мастерили сами. Могу посоветовать вам не подключать те библиотеки, которые вы не используете

Comment: Дак я это и хотел узнать, просто получается Unity не все либы отключает

Comment: К сожалению это плата за лёгкость использования среды разработки.

Comment: Сжимать надо.
Unity написала тему в документации о сжатии. Желательно надо убрать `System.dll` из своего проекта, он весит 1 метр.